# Is there a way to connect the civisepa backend to the profiling in wordpress?

Tags: profile, civisepa, civibanking

I'm trying to connect the payment attributes of my wordpress/civi profiles with civisepa, so that mandates will automatically be updated if a user changes his IBAN, etc. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange alicedd!

Afaik, CiviSEPA mandate information cannot easily be made available in Profiles. CiviSEPA can be made available as a payment processor on CiviCRM Contribution pages though. CiviSEPA would then create a mandate when someone uses the page

If you want to allow constituents updating a mandate you will need to create a custom form / function.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! It helped me a lot